# Google Maps GeoCoder Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I'm trying to make a simple page that allows addresses from a mysql database to be converted to lat and long and then displayed as markers on a map.

Most of the code below comes from the google docs with the addition of some geocoder stuff.

I can successfully alert the correct coordinates (see line 48-53) but then I try to pass them into 'point' variable for google maps to create a marker but nothing appears on the map.

Can anyone see whats wrong with my code? I'm not familiar with Javascript so it could be something really fundamentally wrong.

Thanks

```
 function load() {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
   zoom: 3,
   mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
 });
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

 // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
 downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
   var coords;
   var xml = data.responseXML;
   var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
     var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
     var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       var latpoint = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
       var lngpoint = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
       coords = latpoint + ', ' + lngpoint;
       //alert(coords); //For Testing
     });

     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords);
     var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
     var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: point,
       icon: icon.icon,
       shadow: icon.shadow
     });
     bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
   }
 });
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant parts of the code here, pure pastebin links are frowned upon here. Thanks!

Comment: I marked down line numbers in the original question and thought that was enough.

Comment: nope, the purpose of SO is to build an archive of questions and answers, and questions should contain all relevant info in case the external site goes down

Comment: Sorry. I did try to paste some of the code here but after using the appropriate tags it kept showing errors.

Answer (score 2):

The `LatLng` object constructor is waiting for `Number` type. Here you give it a `string` with the concatened coordinates, wich is wrong.
Look at the [doc here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#LatLng).

Try that instead :

```
var latpoint = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
var lngpoint = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng());

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latpoint, lngpoint);
```

And please refer to the @Pekka 웃 comment to be sure people answer you next time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this freezes the map, no controls show up or markers.

Comment: Ive decided to find the lat and long before inserting on adding data to the database.